# Отправка через другой IP занимает больше времени

Tags: c#

У меня на сервере 2 выделенных айпи. Для того чтобы слать запросы с разных ip я использую след. код. Проблема в том, что обычный гет запрос с интерфейса по умолчанию идёт быстрее чем через этот. Что может быть не так?

```
public class UseIP
    {
        public string IP { get; private set; }

        public UseIP(string IP)
        {
            this.IP = IP;
        }

        public HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            ServicePoint servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
            servicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePoint1, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) =>
            {
                IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(this.IP);
                return new IPEndPoint(address, 0);
            };

            //Will cause bind to be called periodically
            servicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            //will cause bind to be called for each request (as long as the consumer of the request doesn't set it back to true!
            req.KeepAlive = false;

            return req;
        }
}


            UseIP ip = new UseIP("10.18.17.145");

            HttpWebRequest req = ip.CreateWebRequest(new Uri("xxx.ru"));
            using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            }
```

Comment: А чем отличаются эти ip, дальнейшие маршруты в интернет с обоих адресов одинаковы ?

Comment: согласен с Майком, возможно маршруты отличаются. Попробуй провести трасировку